# Rails 4 - config.ssl_options is not working

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ssl

I have enabled the `config.force_ssl=true`, but i am trying to do a redirect to some domain with the help of `config.ssl_options = {redirect: { host: "www.google.com", port: 8080 }}`.

But, `config.ssl_options` is not working.

Ref:

- [Rails SSL](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/32b1c90837570a69841e9ffccff513c74fb7a308/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/ssl.rb)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you referenced is from a commit that doesn't belong to Rails 4.x, here's the version of the [same file in Rails `4.2.5.1`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.5.1/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/ssl.rb)

You'll have to use this syntax:

```
config.ssl_options = { host: "www.google.com", port: 8080 }
```

Comment: Thanks Simone Carletti